# Generate getters and setters not working in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, spring-tool-suite

Generate getters and setters not working in Spring Tool Suite.

Getting below error:
`NoClassDefFoundError` for `org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/util/ElementValidator`

How to resolve this error?

**Exception Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/util/ElementValidator
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.AddGetterSetterAction.run(AddGetterSetterAction.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.AddGetterSetterAction.run(AddGetterSetterAction.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332
```

Comment: Which Eclipse and STS version? How do you call the command (menu, content assist, etc.)?

Comment: I am using STS version 3.5.0. Getting error on Right Click --> Source --> Generate getters and setters

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with STS 3.9.6?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a real problem with the installation. I think you can try two things:

1.) start STS/Eclipse from the command line using the `-clean` option. Sometimes that helps to let the runtime re-calculate dependencies.

2.) if 1.) doesn't work, then I would suggest to re-install STS from a fresh distribution download.